# Bootstrap 3: triple nested list on a navbar default fixed top inverse does not drop down...

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, menubar

I've been trying to get a the menu to drop, from an navbar navbar fixed top navbar inverse, additionally there is a toggle button to make the menu responsive on a small screen... menu is drop down and then drop right... well it doesn't drop down...

also I'm wondering if we can combine a drop down with an accordion? as the menu is contains a quite a few categories and a lot of sub categories?

Thanks,

Max

```
<div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>MENU</button>  
    </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active" class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Home<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Last Minute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News Letter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Africa<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flights</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ferry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Train</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Overland</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Destinations<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">      
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Burundi<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bujumbura</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Gorilla</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Kenya<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nairobi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Mombasa</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rwanda<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Kigali</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Gorilla</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"Safaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Tanzania<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dar es Salaam</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Arusha</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Kilimanjaro</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zambia<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lusaka</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Zambezi River</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Safaris</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zanzibar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Stonetown</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Beach</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Festivals</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Excursions</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Serene<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Members<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rates<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data=toggle="dropdown">Burundi<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                     <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                     <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Kenya<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                     <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                     <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Rwanda<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Tanzania<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zambia<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Zanzibar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu-right">
                                    <li><a href="#">Pacakges</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Transfers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                             </ul>
                         </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">High Resolutions Pictures</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>             
        </div>
    </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: looks like it works fine on regular browser ... please try asking one question at a time... this way you get more answers

Comment: Hi Nolawi, nope I've tried again on different browsers, it looks fine, the design is fluid, the toggle button work, but menu is not dropping down...

Comment: got it but the question is unclear.. what is your first question

Comment: Maybe my html bootstrap coding is not correct because the drop down menu is not working and I've tried in different browsers, I tried to look at the code, but cannot find the mistake...